# jQuery EasyUI: relative panel/layout dimensions (in percent)

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I am using the jQuery EasyUI layout class (http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/layout.php) for a website. Within a layout-div, regions (north, south, west, east and center) can be placed.

I wanted to make the dimensions of the north and south panels relative to the container rather than giving them absolute px-values. So I wanted to move from this

```
<div id="cc" class="easyui-layout" style="width:200px;height:400px;">
    <div data-options="region:'north',title:'North',split:true" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div data-options="region:'south',title:'South',split:true" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div data-options="region:'center',title:'center'"></div>
</div>
```

to this

```
<div id="cc" class="easyui-layout" style="width:200px;height:400px;">
    <div data-options="region:'north',title:'North',split:true" style="height:25%;"></div>
    <div data-options="region:'south',title:'South',split:true" style="height:25%;"></div>
    <div data-options="region:'center',title:'center'"></div>
</div>
```

While the first version works just fine (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56VNr/2/)), the second does not (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/drHUE/)). Does anyone have an idea why not, i.e. how to make the panels relative in their dimensions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<div id="cc" class="easyui-layout" style="width:200px;height:400px;">
    <div data-options="region:'north',title:'North',split:true" class="north"></div>
    <div data-options="region:'south',title:'South',split:true" class="south"></div>
    <div data-options="region:'center',title:'center'"></div>
</div>

.north
{
    height:25%;
}
.south
{
    height:25%;
}
```